# IntelliJ Idea Community Edition - how to run all Dart unit tests in a project

Tags: intellij-idea, dart

If I right click in a test file I can choose to run it.  How do I run all the tests in my dart project within IntelliJ.

In VSCode an action exists that scans the project for files labelled _test.dart, is this VSCode / plugin specific or is it possible to do this in Intellij?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In [Dart Test](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2019.2/run-debug-configuration-dartunit.html) run configuration, you can set **Test Mode** to **All in Folder** to run all files that end with `_test.dart` in specified directory (similar to running `pub run test path/to/dir` in terminal):

[image]